# MVC PartialView from ajax call not styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to take out a component from a view and place it in a Partial View.  The styling works fine on when it is on the original view.  When I call the partial view, all the styling for the components disappears.  Here is the code from the partial view...

```
<form method="post" action="/controller/function" class="wizard-big">
    <div class="ibox-content">
        <div id="Selector">
            <select name="Selector" class="form-control dual_select" multiple>
                @{
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <option value=@item.id>@item.name</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The ajax call from the main view is here...

```
<script>
        var localModel = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(localModel),
                url: "../shared/ClientProgramSelector",
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).done(function(result) {
                $("#clientProgramSelectorPlaceholder").html(result);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And, finally, the styling is all located in the styles section at the bottom of the page.

```
@section Scripts {
    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib_bower/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib_bower/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="~/lib_bower/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib_bower/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    </environment>

    <script src="~/lib/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/plugins/dualListbox/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I have tested other styling, and it is just not this item, all other styles are lost from the partial view to the main view.  So, there is obviously something that I am doing wrong, I just can't find it.  Thanks.

Comment: looks fine. Try reloading the project once and open the page in incognito. I once had faced similar issue.

Comment: Also, you should use `Html.DropDownListFor` instead of forming the select manually

Comment: Just tried that, still not working.

Comment: if using google chrome press F12, settings a turn off caching. Then F5

Comment: That still did not work unfortunately

Comment: did you placed your controller in shared folder/?

Comment: i think you are using any kind of jQuery functionality for your select control